# OpenTelemetry Lambda Layer Logs | Golang

Tags: go, amazon-cloudwatch, open-telemetry, aws-lambda-layers

Is there a way for the info logs to be removed? CloudWatch is swamped due to the Lambda Layer Collector logs.

```
info    Exporter is starting... 
{
    "kind": "exporter",
    "data_type": "traces",
    "name": "otlp"
}
.....
info    Processor started.  
{
    "kind": "processor",
    "name": "groupbytrace",
    "pipeline": "traces"
}
.....
info    shutting down the event manager 
{
    "kind": "processor",
    "name": "groupbytrace",
    "pipeline": "traces",
    "pending-events": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help those who are trying to turn off the info logs.

```golang
nopCore := zap.WrapCore(func(zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {
    return zapcore.NewNopCore()
})
```

And add that to the CollectorSettings:

```golang
params := service.CollectorSettings{
    BuildInfo: component.BuildInfo{
        Command:     "otelcol",
        Description: "Lambda Collector",
        Version:     Version,
    },
    ConfigProvider: c.configProvider,
    Factories:      c.factories,
    LoggingOptions: []zap.Option{nopCore},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to override the default config for the collector that is part of that layer. Probably build a custom collector. Read this section in the docs and you'll see why debug is on: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda/blob/main/collector/README.md#configuration

Here is the main repo for the layer too: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda

Comment: I meant the Lambda Extension part, not the Collector itself. I also have the custom config and removed the `logging` part. But if you are going to the CloudWatch logs, it will have a bunch of logs that I think are using a `log.Print`

Comment: The collector is what is forwarding the messages to the tracing backend. It's part of the lambda layer that is run.

Comment: I think I found a way to turn off the logging so the info logs will not swamp the CloudWatch.

`nopCore := zap.WrapCore(func(zapcore.Core) zapcore.Core {return zapcore.NewNopCore()})`

And add that to the CollectorSettings as `LoggingOptions: []zap.Option{nopCore},`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was resolved by this PR - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-lambda/pull/316/files

Try to set env var "OPENTELEMETRY_EXTENSION_LOG_LEVEL: warn" for example, in my case it removed all info events from OpenTelemetry Lambda Extension Layer